# How to cat in for loop

Tags: bash, directory, scripts, cat

I have 500 folders containing many *_1.fastq.gz and *_2.fastq.gz files per folder.

I want to:

```
cat *_1.fastq.gz > Combined *_1.fastq.gz & cat *_2.fastq.gz > Combined_2.fastq.gz
```

per folder.

How do I achieve this?
I would like to learn some bash, I am comfortable with python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in {1..2} ; do cat *_$i.fastq.gz >>Combined_$i.fastq.gz ; done
```

This probably won't work well, as concatenated gzip files ; I would imagine you would prefer to use `zcat *_$i.fastq.gz >>Combined_$i.fastq` & then gzip; or perhaps better, simply scrap the idea of cat & do this:

```
for i in {1..2} ; do tar -c *_$i.fastq.gz >Combined_$i.fastq.gz.tar; done
```

per folder - then to recurse the folders, simply enclose the line above in a further loop, and run this from the top-level folder:

```
for f in *; do
  pushd . ; cd $f
      for i in {1..2} ; do tar -c *_$i.fastq.gz >Combined_$i.fastq.gz.tar; done
  popd
done
```

So here, the loop index $f picks every folder; saves your place; cd's to the folder; executes the loop; returns to original directory & loops again.

The pushd / popd are there to ensure an error doesn't have you roaming the filesystem! Not strictly neccesary, but useful to learn.

Comment: with some slight tweaks I got it to do what I wanted. I changed back the tar -c to cat, since cat does exactly what I need.

Thanks for solving my problem

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a great example for learning bash, but the simplest way is:

```
zcat *_1.fastq.gz | gzip > Combined_1.fastq.gz &
zcat *_2.fastq.gz | gzip > Combined_2.fastq.gz
```

Using a loop:

```
for f in *_1.fastq.gz; do
    zcat "$f"
done | gzip > Combined_1.fastq.gz
```

Notes

- you iterate over the results of a glob pattern -- do not be tempted to parse the output of `ls` (http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)
- quote your `"$variables"` when you want the value
- you can redirect or pipe the output of an entire for or while loop.

Answer (score -1):

You need something like

```
for d in */
    do cd $d && cat *_1.fastq.gz > Combined_1.fastq.gz && cat *_2.fastq.gz > Combined_2.fastq.gz
done
```